# Incorporating ESAPI log4j requirements

Tags: log4j, log4j2, esapi

I have a simple XML format log4j config file. I am trying to incorporate ESAPI log4j requirement of adding their factory.

How do I reconcile this format (I am guessing strict XML format) to simple XML format that I am using below. If I just add this line in, ESAPI just dies with the exception:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerFactory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerFactory would be for Log4j 1.x, not Log4j 2.x. You might try including the log4j-1.2-api jar from Log4j2.